# How to debug an error in WebKit that happens when an external link is clicked? (Preventing page change in WebKit Inspector)

Tags: javascript, debugging

When I click a link that's supposed to run some Ajax code, I am getting an error, and the page is following the link.  The thing is, my ajax function prevents the link from being followed (`event.preventDefault(); return false`).  But because the error is being thrown in that Ajax function, that `event.preventDefault()` is never executed, so the page changes and I can't debug the error.

All I need to do is tell WebKit to not follow the link, so I can read the error that happens right there.  How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add the complete JS code that is causing the error or provide a link to the page where the error occurs?

Comment: It's independent of the error, it's overly complicated code haha…  I'll write a quick example.

Comment: sanitize your links before debugging: `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function (v) { v.href = '#' + v.href; });` , thus making them NOT navigate away from the page.

Comment: This is basically what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/viatropos/XkMtZ/8/

Comment: @c69, that's good, I'll do that in some places.  However, there are other edge cases that change the page too, such as a dynamically generated link, or some people even do `$("div").click(function() {  window.location.href = "http://github.com"; });`, haha.  The main question/problem is: _how do you prevent webkit from following a link_.  Being able to do that would make life very easy, I don't have to try and figure out how to prevent a link from being followed if it's in some obscure/external library.

Answer (score -1):

If you're dealing with an < a > tag, another thing you can try is adding the following to the A tag:

```
onclick="return false"
```